# Trying to get data from json

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Origin': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
}
base_url='https://api.reedexpo.com/v1/organisations/'

params = {
    'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for vanilla JavaScript 3.27.1',
    'x-algolia-application-id': 'XD0U5M6Y4R',
    'x-algolia-api-key': 'd5cd7d4ec26134ff4a34d736a7f9ad47',
}

data = '{"params":"query=&page=0&facetFilters=&optionalFilters=%5B%5D"}'

resp = requests.post('https://xd0u5m6y4r-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/event-edition-eve-e6b1ae25-5b9f-457b-83b3-335667332366_en-us/query', params=params, headers=headers, data=data).json()
productlinks=[]
for item in resp['hits']:
    url=base_url+item['organisationGuid']+"/exhibiting-organisations?eventEditionId="+item['eventEditionExternalId']
    productlinks.append(url)
    
for link in productlinks:
    title=link['_embedded']['companyName'].json()
    print(title)
```

I am trying to get data but they show me `str must be integer` these is the page link where I get json https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/en-us/attend/exhibitor-list/exhibitor-details.org-8e39ea94-5500-4798-8fe6-b8fab875dd87.html#

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these it  will work for you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Origin': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
}
base_url='https://api.reedexpo.com/v1/organisations/'

params = {
    'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for vanilla JavaScript 3.27.1',
    'x-algolia-application-id': 'XD0U5M6Y4R',
    'x-algolia-api-key': 'd5cd7d4ec26134ff4a34d736a7f9ad47',
}

data = '{"params":"query=&page=0&facetFilters=&optionalFilters=%5B%5D"}'

resp = requests.post('https://xd0u5m6y4r-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/event-edition-eve-e6b1ae25-5b9f-457b-83b3-335667332366_en-us/query', params=params, headers=headers, data=data).json()
productlinks=[]
for item in resp['hits']:
    url=base_url+item['organisationGuid']+"/exhibiting-organisations?eventEditionId="+item['eventEditionExternalId']
    productlinks.append(url)
    
    
for link in productlinks:
    headers = {"x-clientid": "uhQVcmxLwXAjVtVpTvoerERiZSsNz0om"}
    data = requests.get(link, headers=headers).json()
    for t in data["_embedded"]:
        
        d=t["multilingual"]
        for u in d:
           k=u["address"]
           print(k)
```

output:

```
{'addressLine1': '2950 Fretz Valley Rd', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'Perkasie', 'stateProvince': 'PA', 'postcode': '18944-4034', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': '304 Rio Del Norte Road', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'St. Augustine', 'stateProvince': 'Florida', 'postcode': '32095', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': '1752 Anklam Ct.', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'Rio Rico', 'stateProvince': 'Arizona', 'postcode': '85648', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': '56965 Panchita Road', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'Yucca Valley', 'stateProvince': 'California', 'postcode': '92284', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': '10887 Commerce Way Unit A', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'Fontana', 'stateProvince': 'California', 'postcode': '92337', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': '14832 Arrow Hwy', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'Baldwin Park', 'stateProvince': 'CA', 'postcode': '91706-1823', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': 'No.99 Haixi Road', 'addressLine2': 'Jiaonan Qingdao', 'city': 'Qingdao', 'stateProvince': 'Shandong', 'postcode': '266400', 'countryCode': 'CHN', 'country': 'China'}
{'addressLine1': '1 John C Dean Memorial Blvd', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'Cumberland', 'stateProvince': 'RI', 'postcode': '02864-4801', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': '2 Marlborough Rd', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'West Hempstead', 'stateProvince': 'NY', 'postcode': '11552-1712', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': 'Near Kmv College', 'addressLine2': 'Tanda Road', 'city': 'Jalandhar', 'stateProvince': 'Punjab', 'postcode': '144004', 'countryCode': 'IND', 'country': 'India'}
{'addressLine1': '809 S Hamilton St', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'Sullivan', 'stateProvince': 'IL', 'postcode': '61951-2209', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': '2924 State Highway 155', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'Sayner', 'stateProvince': 'Wisconsin', 'postcode': '54560', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': '99 Madison Ave Fl 620', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'New York', 'stateProvince': 'NY', 'postcode': '10016-7419', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
{'addressLine1': 'E-5, MIDC', 'addressLine2': 'Waluj', 'city': 'Aurangabad', 'stateProvince': 'Maharashtra', 'postcode': '431136', 'countryCode': 'IND', 'country': 'India'}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get `companyName` from the request you can use next example:

```py
import requests


organisationGuid = "org-8e39ea94-5500-4798-8fe6-b8fab875dd87"
eventGuid = "eve-e6b1ae25-5b9f-457b-83b3-335667332366"

url = f"https://api.reedexpo.com/v1/organisations/{organisationGuid}/exhibiting-organisations?eventEditionId={eventGuid}"

headers = {"x-clientid": "uhQVcmxLwXAjVtVpTvoerERiZSsNz0om"}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
print(data["_embedded"][0]["companyName"])
```

Prints:

```
21st Century Inc
```

Comment: but how I rotate  for loop for  `organisationGuid` and `eventGuid`then can I get also other `titles` and also the `address`

Comment: any solution if you recommend me?

Comment: To get address you can go with `print(data['_embedded'][0]['multilingual'][0]['address'])` but result will differ from your posted one

Comment: Can you share solution

Comment: Andrej already provided a solution to fix your main issue. Simply adapt it, while extracting  address instead of company.

Comment: Main issue they give  data of only one link but I get data of all the  link

Comment: For these purpose I have to rotate 'organisationGuid' but how I can apply for loop these is main problem

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - focus of these question seemed to be fixing the error you got and get the company.

Comment: I create question can you answer that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246318/discussion-between-hedgehog-and-amen-aziz).

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically out for the address as posted in your question, the following code in python can reproduce the get request send by my browser:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'x-clientid': 'uhQVcmxLwXAjVtVpTvoerERiZSsNz0om',
    'x-correlationid': 'cc4d6e40-2285-4585-b281-4ba84761d289',
}

params = {
    'eventEditionId': 'eve-e6b1ae25-5b9f-457b-83b3-335667332366',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.reedexpo.com/v1/organisations/org-8e39ea94-5500-4798-8fe6-b8fab875dd87/exhibiting-organisations', params=params, headers=headers)
```

This will return a bit more info, but we can filter it for address details only:

```
print(response.json()["_embedded"][0]["multilingual"][0]["address"])
{'addressLine1': '2950 Fretz Valley Rd', 'addressLine2': '', 'city': 'Perkasie', 'stateProvince': 'PA', 'postcode': '18944-4034', 'countryCode': 'USA', 'country': 'United States'}
```